# iOS - close keyboard when button is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I currently have a `textfield`, a `picker`, a `button`, and several `textviews`/`labels`.

The `textfield` prompts a number only keyboard, I want the keyboard to dismiss when the one button is pressed.

Here is a snippet of some of the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var provincePicker: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var calcButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var incomeLabel: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var salaryTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var beforeTax: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var provincialTax: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var federalTax: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var afterTax: UITextView!
```

...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
  //  numberOnly()
         borders()
         super.viewDidLoad()
         provincePicker.dataSource = self
         provincePicker.delegate = self
    }
```

...

```
     @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton) {
         let formatter           = NSNumberFormatter()
         formatter.numberStyle   = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
         formatter.locale        = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_CA")

         let index = provincePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)

         switch(index) {
         case 0:
            calculate(abBrackets, rates: abRates)   //AB
         //cutting out code here
         dismissKeyboard()
      }

      func dismissKeyboard() {
         self.view.endEditing(true)
      }
```

Comment: On your `main.storyboard`, check if you have multiple connection on your button...

Comment: The buttons only referencing outlet is calcButton function, I tried adding self.view.endEditing(true) to the end of that function, doesn't work.

Comment: What do you exactly want and what's going wrong? Do you want to close the keyboard when the user has pressed the button `1` like you've mentioned in your question or when they've pressed the `calculateButton`?

Comment: @Eendje All I want to happen is the keyboard dismisses when the calculateButton is pressed. The calculateButton function that is attached to it calls a different function with some math in it, but I want the keyboard to dismiss here as well because they keyboard covers the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to call this function when your button is pressed:

```
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Or, in your button function, do this:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

And remember to connect your button to your viewController by control + click on your button and drag it to your controller file, then, on the popup, click on `connection` and select `action` and give it a name:

[image]

Also, check if you have multiple connection on your button, it might be a  problem...

Comment: Still crashes, yes I will edit the main post 1 second

Comment: @MrHaze oups i didn't notice, sorry, i upvote yours to

Comment: I tried adding the self.view.endEditing code to the function that is already ctrl-dragged from the button, and that line of code causes the crash and brings me to my appdelegate.swift. 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Comment: What crash message do you get?

Comment: I think your `salaryTaxField` is not connected properly, remove all it's connections then reconnect.
In your code, you should see a filled in circle next to `@IBOutlet weak var salaryTextField: UITextField!`, if it's not filled that means it's not connected to the UI element.

Comment: @MrHaze reconnecting my textfield worked. I don't know why, it had IBOutlet and a circle where line numbers are.... so much time wasted. Thank you MrHaze and Thomas a

Comment: It's the small things that take time :)
Also, @arthur Please set Thomas a 's answer to the correct one, his answer is clearer than mind for other readers.

Comment: Also, try to make sense of the errors you get, that's a very useful tool for debugging.

Comment: very new to iOS/swift - the errors are very gibberish-y

Comment: MrHaze Thanks you ;) and ,@arthur happy coding !

Comment: You get used to them, the more often they happen. Trust me they are much easier to deal with than other languages. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You just want to end editing when the button is clicked.

You can do that by calling the `endEditing(force: Bool)` function:

which causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.

Use like this:

```
@IBAction func didTapBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Your button needs to be connected to the `@IBAction`. I might be connected to something else. In interface building you might want to `ctr+click` the button, and remove all connections, then connect it to the `@IBAction`.

Comment: Check this out: http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/

Answer (score 1):

First,CTRL-DRAG an target-action(or use addTarget... function programmatically).Second,do like this in your codes:

```
self.inputTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```